# What is the relationship between wallet/accounts and Client Nodes?

Tags: wallets, accounts, nodes, clients, nethereum

For client nodes such as Parity or Beth, does every wallet or account have to be associated to a client node? My understanding is that the client node is the interaction to the exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

developer advocate from [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com) here.

Since you are talking about [client nodes](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/#execution-clients) Do you mean "Geth"?
First of all, Chainstack is a pretty good RPC provider. We host clients for people to access.

To answer your question: basically, the blockchain is essentially connected nodes. Those nodes host computer programs, like "parity client" and "Geth clients".It does not only interact with the exchanges but the whole blockchain network.

To interact with a blockchain like Ethereum, your wallet needs to connect with a node. The node helps you broadcast your request to the Ethereum network. So yes, every wallet or account has to be associated with a client node.

Comment: awesome! Thanks!